# Vuejs 2.1.10 method passed as prop not a function

Tags: vuejs2

I'm very new to Vuejs and JS frameworks in general, so bear with me. I'm trying to call a method that resides in my root component from a child component (2 levels deep) by passing it as a prop, but I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.onChange is not a function
at VueComponent._onChange (category.js:8)
at boundFn (vendor.js?okqp5g:361)
at HTMLInputElement.invoker (vendor.js?okqp5g:2179)
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track by assigning the prop to a method inside the child component, but see what you think:

index.js

```
var app = new Vue({

    el: '#app',
    data: function () {
        return {
            categories: [],
            articles: []
        }

    },

    methods: {
        onChange: function () {

            console.log('first one');

            return function () {
                console.log('second one');
            }

        }

    },
});
```

The html:

```
<div id="app">
    <sidebar :onChange=onChange :categories=categories></sidebar>
    <varticles :articles=articles></varticles>
</div>
```

sidebar.js:

```
Vue.component('sidebar', {

    props: ['onChange', 'categories'],


    methods: {
        _onChange: function () {
            this.onChange();
        }
    },


    template: `
        <div class="sidebar">

        <category v-for="item in categories" :onChange="_onChange" v-bind:category="item"></category>

    </div>
    `
});
```

category.js:

```
Vue.component('category', {

    props: ['category', 'onChange'],


    methods: {
        _onChange: function () {
            this.onChange();
        }
    },


    template: `
        <div class="category">
            <h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>

            <ul>
                <li v-for="option in category.options">
                <input v-on:change="_onChange" v-bind:id="option.tid" type="checkbox" v-model="option.checked">
                 <label v-bind:for="option.tid">{{ option.name }}</label>
                 </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    `
});
```

There's got to be simpler way to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest taking a look at this https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case. A simplified version of your code is in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/641/

When writing props in your templates declare them without Capital letters.
A prop declared as `onChange` in your `props` is equivalent to `on-change` in your html.

```
<sidebar :on-change=onChange :categories=categories></sidebar>
```

Also I would suggest looking at events and non parent-child communication if you want a link between components that are more than 1 level deep. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html?#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: Boom that's it!